# Aura Upload file with inputfield/required field

Tags: lightning-aura-components, fileupload

I have an Aura component with the upload component, but now I want to add an `inputfield` which information should also stored in the file information.
How can I add the information for the `documenttype__c` field?

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId">
    <aura:attribute name="filetype" type="List" default="['.png', '.jpg', '.jpeg']" />
    <aura:attribute name="multiple" type="Boolean" default="true" />
    <aura:attribute name="disabled" type="Boolean" default="true" />
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="encryptedToken" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="documentype__c" type="String" />

    <lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="recordEditForm" objectApiName="ContentVersion">
        <lightning:messages />
        <lightning:inputField fieldName="documenttype__c" />
        <lightning:button class="slds-m-top_small" type="submit" label="Create new" />
    </lightning:recordEditForm>
    
    <lightning:fileUpload label="Attach receipt"
        name="fileUploader"
        multiple="true"
        accept="{!v.filetype}"
        recordId="{!v.recordId}"
        fileFieldName="Guest_Record_fileupload__c"
        fileFieldValue="{!v.encryptedToken}"
        onuploadfinished="{!c.handleUploadFinished}" />  
</aura:component>
```

```
({
    handleUploadFinished: function (cmp, event) {
        // Get the list of uploaded files
        var uploadedFiles = event.getParam("files");
        var documenttype__c = event.getParam("documenttype__c")
        alert("Files uploaded : " + uploadedFiles.length);

        // Get the file name
        uploadedFiles.forEach(file => console.log(file.name));
    }
})
```

Comment: This is Aura, not LWC?

Comment: Thanks for your editing.

Comment: No more ideas??